# Devextreme React Datebox - Localization

Tags: reactjs, дата, devexpress

Подскажите, как прикрутить локализацию к компоненту Datebox?
Надо, чтобы месяцы писались на русском и формат даты выводился русский.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DateBox from "devextreme-react/date-box";

function Root() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DateBox type="date" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы найдете тут всю информацию https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/Localization/#Localize_Dates_Numbers_and_Currencies

```
import { locale } from "devextreme/localization";

locale("ru");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я видел эту информацию, но не правильно с ней работал. Надо быть проще - импорт и locale("ru") и всё.

Comment: Отлично) Успехов вам в ReactJS))